# How can I add more trees to a random forest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

Is there a canonical way to iteratively add trees to a random forest?
Let's say I am using the `caret` package and I use something like

```
rf_fit <- train(y~.,data=df,method="rf",ntree = N)
```

for some N and then I would like to continue adding trees to it, how would I go about that?

Comment: Please specify from which library is the function `train`

Comment: Thanks, edited. I am using caret

Comment: I do not think this is possible with caret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own function and `lapply` across `ntree`:

```
data <- iris

fit_tree <- function(ntree){
rf_fit <- train(Species~.,data=iris,method="rf",ntree = ntree)
}

fit <- lapply(seq(100,500,100),fit_tree)
```

Here `fit` is a list of 5 `randomForests` model each fitted with the `ntrees` specified in the first argument of `lapply`.
I don't know if is possible to add trees to the same model. If the model fitted with *n* trees don't reach the accuracy you want, you can simply re-fit the model with *n*+100 trees for example (but keep in mind that increasing the number of trees doesn't necessarily improve the accuracy, indeed, it could worsen performance. In the `caret package` the default `ntrees` is 500 as suggested by Breiman in his original paper (Breiman, 2001)).

**EDIT**

to add trees to an existing `randomForests` model you can do something like this:

```
fit_tree <- function(how.many){
rf_fit <- randomForest(Species~.,data=iris)
new_fit <- grow(rf_fit,how.many)
}

p <-lapply(seq(10,100,10),fit_tree)
```

Here the starting `ntree` is the default one (I. e. 500) and the `lapply` adds 10 trees for each iteration.
With this approach is not so helpful to tune the `mtry` parameter with `caret` since the best parameter values would be found only for the first call to `randomForest`, but not for the updated model

Comment: In your code, you fit 3 trees, right? one for 100, one for 500 and one for 100 as the value of ntree, right? 
Also this retrains from scratch any time instead of keeping the previous trees? I specifically want to train a few trees, see how it does, keep them, but add more to the ensemble. I do not think this is what your snipped does. Am I wrong?

Comment: in the code, 5 models are fitted with ntree= 100, 200,300, 400, 500 (look at `?seq`).. however, you are right, the code retrain each model with a different number of trees. Add additional trees to an existing random forests model can be done with `grow` in the `randomForest`  package (I don't know if it is possible to link `grow` to `caret` in some way). If your model doesn't reach the performance you expected you can simply try to increase the numbers of trees and re-run the fitting(but it is unlikely to be helpful). I will edit my answer to include the case you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. the grow function is pretty much what I was looking for, I will try to see how to make it work with caret, but working with the rf package directly is also fine.